# Put every 2 columns into a new worksheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a VBA scrip that can take every 2 columns and turn into a new worksheet in the same excel file? I have 384 sets of columns needing to be turned into new sheets. I also have 618 data points for each column, if this is useful for setting the VBA parameters.

I have tried searching for this answer online, and have found my problem solved for splitting every 900 rows into a new worksheet in the same excel file, but nothing for columns. Please see the code below. As I have only recorded a macro and not written a script, I am a novice to VBA. I tried replacing the word Row with Column in the below script and changing the 900 to 2, but that did not work either.

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Long, myRow As Long, mySheet As Worksheet
lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For myRow = 2 To lastRow Step 900
Set mySheet = Worksheets.Add
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(myRow & ":" & myRow + 899).EntireRow.Copy       mySheet.Range("A1")
Next myRow
End Sub
```

I really appreciate your time and help with this matter as I will be using this code dozens of times.

Thank you!

Comment: Try this: (1) Open your file and make sure there is only one spreadsheet with your data (delete any other empty spreadsheet), (2) Go to the Developers/Macros tab (if not visible, make it visible through the settings), (3) Click the Record Macro button, (4) Create a new Spreadsheet, (5) If needed, return to your original Spreadsheet, (6) Select and copy the first column, (7) for to the new Spreadsheet and paste into the desire column, (8) repeat the copy-paste with the second column, (9) return to your main spreadsheet, (10) stop macro recording. This will create a function (continued...)

Comment: Please specifiy what does not work, where an error comes up and also show us your code. No one will program for you, but we will help you to find the fault

Comment: with the recorded actions and which you can adapt to your specific needs.

Comment: FDavidov, thank you.This is usually how I create macros. I thought there might be a simpler way, so that is why I posted my question. I completed 7 sheets and will continue on doing this 377 more times, because I do not know how to create a loop since I am only in record mode. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is far from being correct, but at least you made some effort of posting some code. The below is tested, and works. I prefer using Ron De Bruin's function for finding last cells. You can find it on his site, but pasted herebelow as well.

```
Sub test()

  Dim lastRow As Integer, lastColumn As Integer, v As Variant
  Dim ws As Worksheet, nws As Worksheet, i As Integer

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  lastRow = RDB_Last(1, ws.Cells)
  lastColumn = RDB_Last(2, ws.Cells)

  For i = 1 To lastColumn Step 2

    v = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i), ws.Cells(lastRow, i + 1))
    Set nws = Worksheets.Add
    nws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(v, 1) + i, UBound(v, 2)).Value = v
    Set nws = Nothing

  Next i

End Sub


Function RDB_Last(choice As Integer, rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
'Returns address of last cell. row or column
' A choice of 1 = last row.
' A choice of 2 = last column.
' A choice of 3 = last cell.
   Dim lrw As Long
   Dim lcol As Integer

   Select Case choice

   Case 1:
      On Error Resume Next
      RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
      On Error GoTo 0

   Case 2:
      On Error Resume Next
      RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Column
      On Error GoTo 0

   Case 3:
      On Error Resume Next
      lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
      On Error GoTo 0

      On Error Resume Next
      lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                     After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                     Lookat:=xlPart, _
                     LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                     MatchCase:=False).Column
      On Error GoTo 0

      On Error Resume Next
      RDB_Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
      If Err.Number > 0 Then
         RDB_Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
         Err.Clear
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0

   End Select
End Function
```